# Retrive Wordoffsets for interim results

Tags: c#, google-cloud-speech

I am using the following config to retrieve results from the speech api:

```
StreamingConfig = new StreamingRecognitionConfig
{
    Config = new RecognitionConfig
    {
        Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
        SampleRateHertz = 8000,
        LanguageCode = languageCode,
        EnableWordTimeOffsets = true
    },
    InterimResults = true
}
```

When retriving a result, the `WordTimeOffsets` should be included in the `WordInfos` of the property `Alternatives`.
Unfortunately, I am only getting `WordInfos` for results where `IsFinal = true`.
When retrieving interim results the array of words is empty although a  transcript is there.

I have installed 1.1.0-beta02 from nuget and setup a .NET Core project.

I have read through the documentation and through some articles in the internet but found no hint that the wordinfos are only filled for final results.

Please let me know if you need some additional information.